# CSS nav menu (background gradient issue)

Tags: html, css

I have made a multi tier navigation menu and have an issue where tiers below tier 1 have an unexpected block to the left of the options. I assume the issue stems from having a background gradient but have not been able to resolve the issue so far. Can anyone shed any light on this for me please?
have put a link below.

http://tinypic.com/r/2pr7alj/5

**The HTML code below:**

```
    <div id="menu">
        <ul class="menu1"><!--Start of menu level 1-->
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","#","Home")
            </li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("A","#","A")  
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("B","#","B")
                <ul class="menu2"><!--Start of menu level 2-->
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("1","#","1")
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("2","#","2") 
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("3","#","3")
                    </li><!--End of menu level 2-->
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("C","#","C")
            </li>
        </ul><!--End of menu level 1-->
      </div>
```

**Below is the CSS related to the menu.**

```
#menu {
width:100%;
height:44px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7db9e8 19%,#2989d8 51%,#1e5799 67%,#1e5799           81%,#207cca 100%);}

ul.menu1 {
list-style-type:none;
float:left;
margin-top:0px;}

ul.menu2, ul.menu3, ul.menu4{
list-style-type:none;}

ul li {
float:left;
width:200px;
position:relative;}

ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:1em;
color:#fff;
font-weight:bold;
display:block;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
margin:0px;
line-height:32px;
border:1px solid;
text-align:center;
white-space:nowrap;}

ul.menu2 {
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:-40px;}

ul.menu3, ul.menu4 {
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:160px;
top:0px;}

ul li:hover ul.menu2 {
display:block;
background-color:#2472bb;}

ul ul li:hover ul.menu3 {
display:block;
background-color:#2472bb;}

ul ul ul li:hover ul.menu4 {
display:block;
background-color:#2472bb;}

ul li:hover > a {
background-color:#839ab6;}

ul li:hover a:hover {
background-color:#538dd5;}
```

Comment: Might want to post some code.

Comment: a fiddle would be nice as well...

Comment: Your `<ul>` may have some padding applied by default. Also, missing some closing `</li>` tags. http://jsfiddle.net/EcW3X/

Comment: Removing the "left:-40" from menu 2 did the trick! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's extra left padding to your menu1, menu2, etc. for some reason. Not sure how. But all you need to do is set padding-left to 0:

```
ul.menu1, ul.menu2, ul.menu3, ul.menu4{
padding-left:0;
}
```

And remove "left:-40" from ul.menu2{...} to make it look nice.